# Django: AND filter on related objects

Tags: python, django

Imagine:

```py
class Player(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Game(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Match(model.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='matches')

class Score(model.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name='scores')
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='scores')
```

I'd like a query that returns all Match objects that contain a list of players.

I'm really quite stuck. Say I have a list of Player objects (a QuerySet or a list of PKs, is fine), I can get all the matches ANY player played in as follows:

```py
Match.objects.filter(scores__player__in=players)
```

But a list of matches that ALL players played in is eluding me.

I'm wondering if there is a canonical approach to this, it is a simple AND query on related set of objects. I want matches where player[1] is in scores AND player[2] is in scores etc.

Ultimately I want a list of games but I think that is easy from a list of matches:

```py
Game.objects.filter(matches__in=matches)
```

I have considered ArrayAgg but it's both Postgresql specific and I've not found a syntax for filtering on membership. I have looked at Subquery but also not found a syntax that helps me here yet. There are also performance issues.

Ideas I'm toying with are:

1. Annotate a Match query with an ArrayAgg of Player objects that are related via a Score and return matches for which each player is in that list.
2. Annotate with a Subquery that lists all the Player objects that are related via a Score and return matches for which each player is in that list.
3. Find an intersection of Match queries on individual players.

But thus far I am defeated.

**Update**

I am no longer defeated but still welcome any input on a canonical method as I fear none of the three methods I have explored are canonical and offer advantages and disadvantages .

Using intersections:

```py
players = ['<a list of PKs>']
matches = Match.objects.filter(scores__player=players[0])
for pk in players[1:]:
    matches = Match.intersection(Match.objects.filter(scores__player=pk))
```

This does find all the Match objects that ALL the players competed in and is evaluated as a single SQL statement, but has one Select statement per player so I hold concern this is not the most elegant or efficient method.

Using joins:

```py
players = ['<a list of PKs>']
matches = Match.objects.filter(scores__player=players[0])
for pk in players[1:]:
    matches = Match.filter(scores__player=pk))
```

Somewhat terser but suffering similar problems. Finds them all, but adds a join for every player and doesn't scale well.

using arrays:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
players = ['<a list of PKs>']
matches = Match.objects.annotate(match_players=ArrayAgg(F('scores__player'), distinct=True)).filter(match_players__contains=players)
```

This borders on a perfect solution, canoncial, except that it is database engine specific (postgresql), but maintains a single terse query without exploding intersections or joins to achieved the goal.

Comment: Why doesn't your solution work? `Match.objects.filter(scores__player__in=players)` seems to do the job. I'm quite confused, perhaps that's still not clear in the question.

Comment: Because it returns all the Matches in which ANY of the listed players have scores. And I am after the matches that ALL of the listed players have scores. What is unclear there? I'm curious.

Comment: @BerndWechner there really is no elegant method for what you want simply because you want to compare the results of multiple rows. This is not really possible unless one makes joins (in your case you used intersections). The problem is as the number of rows you want increases so does the complexity of your query (due to the increasing number of joins). You can go the join route by chaining the filters: `for pk in players:    queryset = queryset.filter(scores__player=pk)`

Comment: Why thank you. That works too. And is slightly more elegant.